# How do I check a text file for a certain string and notify when that string has been added?

Tags: vb.net

What I'm trying to do is monitor a chat log for a game that I play. I want to make a program that will notify me anytime my character name has been mentioned in the chat. If my name is mentioned in the chat it tells me. Then it tells me again after it scans the file again over and over again. Every time the file changes. I only want to be notified once of each instance of my name being mentioned. Can someone help me correct this code to do what I need?

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Changed(sender As Object, e As IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    If e.FullPath = "C:\Games\Chat\Logs\chat.txt" Then
        Dim fileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(e.FullPath)

        ' Convert the text to lower case to provide for better trigger matching if case sensitivity
        ' isn't an issue.
        If fileContents.ToLower.Contains("palumbo") Then
            Dim strMessage As String
            strMessage = "Name Mentioned In Chat!" & vbNewLine
            txtMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            txtMessage.SelectionFont = New Font("Arial", 18, FontStyle.Bold)
            txtMessage.AppendText(strMessage)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The way this is working is it checks the file sees that it was mentioned then it tells me. Then if the file changes anything at all added to the file it scans it again and tells me again. Even if my name hasn't been mentioned again. I'm not sure what code I need to add to only tell me once each time its mentioned even if my name is mentioned 100 times. I only want it to tell me each time it's mentioned. Then wait for the next. Maybe by checking the line number when my name is mentioned and if the number is greater then the last time mentioned then tell me if not then skip it?

I'm not sure how to do that though.

Comment: Instead of using `ReadAllText` I recommend [StreamReader.Read(buffer,index,count)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/9kstw824%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which reads the file beginning at the given `index`. In the first run `index` would be `0` but at the end you memorise its last position. In the second run index would be that last position and so on. So you will skip all already scanned text.

Comment: Can you give me an example with this code? I'm new to programming so I'm not the best at all this yet.

Comment: I saw that you already marked @Chase´s answer as accepted so I guess you don´t need my solution anymore :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a count of the number of occurrences of your character name and be notified when that changes. Also, if you read from a file that changes often, you're likely to get an `IOException` so one way around it is to make a copy and read that.

```
Private Sub FileSystemWatcher1_Changed(sender As Object, e As IO.FileSystemEventArgs) Handles FileSystemWatcher1.Changed
    If e.FullPath = "C:\Games\Chat\Logs\chat.txt" Then
        'temp file in different dir from the one being monitored
        Dim tmpfile As String = "C:\chat.txt"

        FileCopy(e.FullPath, tmpfile)

        Dim fileContents As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(tmpfile)

        Static chatNameOccurences As Integer = 0
        Dim chatName As String = "palumbo"

        ' Convert the text to lower case to provide for better trigger matching if case sensitivity
        ' isn't an issue.
        If fileContents.ToLower.Contains(chatName) Then
            Dim occurrences As Integer = CountMatches(fileContents.ToLower, chatName)
            If Not occurrences.Equals(chatNameOccurences) Then
                chatNameOccurences = occurrences
                Dim strMessage As String
                strMessage = "Name Mentioned In Chat " & chatNameOccurences & " times!" & vbNewLine
                txtMessage.SelectionColor = Color.Red
                txtMessage.SelectionFont = New Font("Arial", 18, FontStyle.Bold)
                txtMessage.AppendText(strMessage)
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Public Function CountMatches(ByVal value As String, ByVal ch As String) As Integer
    Return New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(ch).Matches(value).Count
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know why but the FileCopy part of the code is not working. It's not copying the file to the destination. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: It's not throwing any errors. It's just not working at all. I check the C:\ and there isn't any chat.txt. It's not creating the copy at all.

Comment: Strange...not sure how that could be unless you typed it wrong or it's never firing the changed event. Put a break point on that FileCopy line, check to see if 1) it breaks there and 2) when you step to the next line, the file is created

Comment: It's working for some reason the first time I ran it didn't compile correctly or something. I ran it the second time and it works as intended although its not really what I'm looking for. I'm looking for something that checks the log and only tells me when something recent is posted. Maybe have it check the last line of the txt file and if the line number is still the same then don't display it. If the line number is bigger then display it. That's kind of something what I'm looking for. This will work till I can figure out how to do it the way I need it though thank you.

Comment: Actually that wouldn't work either it would have to check the total lines of the text file and then check to see if the very last line of the text file is a higher number then the last time it was mentioned. All this confuses me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your original issue...when you said: _"I'm not sure what code I need to add to only tell me once each time its mentioned even if my name is mentioned 100 times"_ , did you mean you only wanted to be notified once or 100 times? In that example, my code would notify you 100 times...every time your name is mentioned.

Comment: Well what I mean is if I am in the game all day long and my name is mentioned 20 times during the day I just want it to display a message to me saying it was mentioned. Then the next time my name is mentioned display a new message to me again. Without displaying the ones that were already mentioned. The chat log is never deleted I have to delete it manually once in a while. So my name could be mentioned in the log 1000 times over months or something. I just want the current ones mentioned to me as they happen. I apologize for the confusion I'm terrible at explaining things.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work... Let's say you're going to play all day long and your name is mentioned at 8AM. You want to be notified then? Then it's mentioned again at 9AM. You want to be notified then? If your name is mentioned 20 times throughout the day, you don't want to be notified all 20 times, you just want to be notified once? And if just once, when exactly?

Comment: No the way you said it the first time I want to be told each time. What I meant by not being told about the last one is I don't want to log into the game tomorrow and be told my name was mentioned from yesterday. If that makes sense. If it was mentioned at 8pm tell me if it was mentioned again at 9pm tell me each time.

Comment: My code would notify you each of those 20 times. Then when you log in the next day, assuming the same chat log exists and it's just appending to it, the first time the chat changes for any reason, it will _(incorrectly)_ tell you your name was mentioned because the Static variable `chatNameOccurences` is back at 0. Is that the only issue...that it's not remembering the previous count? If so, you can read/write that in your app settings instead of making it a static variable.

Comment: No not really I was just kind of hoping I could make it display it each time with a DateTime on it so I know when it was done. Rather then how many times and just appending it each time. It works fine how it is I can use it like that. Just seems more convenient to have it tell me each time, but I don't want to keep bothering you because you have definitely done enough.